# Migration of R group in Hofmann rearrangement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

In the mechanism of Hofmann rearrangement, one step involves migration of $R-$ group from carbon to nitrogen as shown:[image] This reaction proceeds even if the migratory aptitude of the $R$ group is poor (like in the case of ethanamide). What motivates the migration of $R$ group and makes the reaction proceed?

---

P.S.: I think the reason cannot be the negative charge on oxygen since it already delocalized by resonance, which shifts the electron cloud partially towards nitrogen, which is in turn partially shifted towards Bromine due to its **-I** effect. Here's my depiction:
[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does alkyl rearrangement happen in the Hofmann rearrangement?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/82990/why-does-alkyl-rearrangement-happen-in-the-hofmann-rearrangement)

Comment: I think it can be viewed (at least for "educative purpose" i.e. "lie for student") as intramolecular substitution - nitrogen electrophilic attack with CO... as leaving group.